# Validate Image with exif_imagetype but still able to upload non image files

Tags: php, phpmailer, exif

I am not sure if my exif_imagetype is coded wrong.  It send the email just fine with photos attached.  But when I try to attach non image files it will still allow me to do so and send the email with the attachment.  Please help.

```
    ob_start();
require("class.phpmailer.php");

    $photo = $_FILES['photo'];

    isset($_POST['submit']);
$active_keys = array();
foreach($_FILES[$photo]['name'] as $key => $filename){
if(!empty($filename)){
    $active_keys[] = $key;
}    }

foreach($active_keys as $key){    
switch(exif_imagetype($_FILES[$photo]['tmp_name'][$key])) {
case IMAGETYPE_JPEG:
case IMAGETYPE_PNG:
    break;
    default:
 echo "{";
 echo        "$errors: 'This is no photo..'\n";
 echo "}";
  exit(0);
    } }
$message = "some message";
$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->From     = ('sample@youdomain.net');
$mail->AddAddress=('sample@youdomain.net');
$mail->Subject  = "Submitted Photos";
$mail->Body     = $message;
$mail->WordWrap = 50;

foreach($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'] as $photo) 
if(!empty($photo)) {
     $mail->AddAttachment($photo);
}

$mail->Send();


header("Location: thankyou.php");
   exit();     
   }}
```

Comment: @Akam I need to validate the attachment as an array (multiple file allow). I use **if(getimagesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'])){** but it give an error message of **Warning: getimagesize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given**. How do I use this code for an array?

Comment: @E G use foreach for array walk, or even a function called array_walk()

Answer (score 0):

use [getimagesize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php) function before processing anything, it provides better result

example:

```
if(getimagesize($fullpath_to_file)){
 //then do something here
}
```